# Delete rows from postgresql table using JDBC connection from pyspark

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark

I have been using mysql connector from pyspark script to delete rows and execute queries from a mariadb (mysql) table. Like below

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='local_idp',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root',
                                         port = '3306')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "DELETE FROM local_table where Country = 'USA'"
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Now I am using postgresql database and need to use JDBC connection. How can I delete rows from a postgresql table using JDBC connection from pyspark script. Please help

Comment: The DELETE statement will work with Postgres as well.

Comment: I need to use JDBC connection to do delete from pyspark. How to frame it to delete rows from postgresql table. Like given in abve example?

Comment: As I said: the DELETE statement will be the same.